# yum suddenly shows 131 updates available

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I am running CentOS and have yum-updatesd running everyday and notifying me of any updates.  A few days ago, yum started telling me that there are 131 updates available.  What would cause it to do this?  Was the CentOS repo just updated?

Comment: Yum is telling you there are 131 updates available because *there are 131 updates available*. When you consider the amount of software installed on your system it shouldn't be a surprise that occasionally you'll have a bunch of updates come down the pipe.

Comment: I know that I should update, and I will be, but I was curious as to why so many would show up all at once.  Based on other answers, it's because CentOS 5.6 was just released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saw the same thing today, I've got 211. It's because of the new release of CentOS.

Major changes in CentOS 5.6 compared to CentOS 5.5 include:

- ext4 is now a fully supported file system
- libvirt was updated to 0.8.2
- bind was updated to 9.7 and supports NSEC3 now.
- ebtables was added
- php53 is available as a php replacement.
- System Security Services Daemon (SSSD) has been added.

Other upgrades include newer version of several wireless drivers, Samba3x, ghostscript, LVM, mod_nss, subversion and gcc, plus others.

Comment: I'll add that bind was NOT updated to 9.7. The existing BIND package is still the same base stable version. The same applies to PHP. However, there are now alternative packages available, bind97 and php53, respectively, which provide the respective versions of the respective packages. In my case, upgrading to BIND 9.7 was a drop-in upgrade (yum remove bind bind-utils bind-libs; yum install bind97; yum bind97-utils).

Answer (score 3):

Centos 5.6 Was released on the 8th April 2011 which is a major upgrade hence the large number of updates yum is reporting

Answer (score 3):

centos 5.6 was released last week so its more than likely this is the number of packages for update to 5.6, for good security i would recommend updating

to list your updates type

```
yum list updates
```